# Can't mix videotestsrc and uridecodebin with GStreamer/videomixer

Tags: gstreamer

How to mix a live source and a non-live source with GStreamer videomixer plug-in?

Gst-launch shows nothing when mixing uridecodebin ( some mpeg video ) & videotestsrc

```
gst-launch \
videomixer name=mix sink_0::zorder=0 sink_1::zorder=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink \
uridecodebin uri=file:///test.mpg ! timeoverlay ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=704 ,height=576 ! queue ! mix.sink_0 \
videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=176,height=144 ! queue ! mix.sink_1
```

But it works if I change both of the source to the mpeg video,

```
gst-launch 
videomixer name=mix sink_0::zorder=0 sink_1::zorder=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink 
uridecodebin uri=file:///test.mpg ! timeoverlay ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=704 ,height=576 ! queue ! mix.sink_0 
uridecodebin uri=file:///test.mpg ! timeoverlay ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=176,height=144 ! queue ! mix.sink_1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I made a silly mistake. Here is my answer to my own question here:
With the above command and the tested video clip, they output different video format.
After forcing the video format of videotestsrc to I420, it works fine.

Here is a command that mixes:

gst-launch -v 
videomixer name=mix sink_0::zorder=0 sink_1::zorder=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink 
uridecodebin uri=file:///media/sf_share/test.mpg ! timeoverlay ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=704 ,height=576 ! videorate force-fps=-1 ! queue ! mix.sink_0 
videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=352,height=288,format=(fourcc)I420 ! timeoverlay ! queue ! mix.sink_1